# Clarifications on the behavior of the AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have this static helper function, to set a daily-repeating alarm:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context, int hh, int mm)
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hh);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mm);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentAlarm, 0);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

I have three places where this helper function is called:

1. When device boots up, I want to re-register the alarm:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
           setAlarm(context, 7, 00);
       }
   }
   ```
2. In one of my activities, call it ActivityA:

   `AlarmReciever.setAlarm(ActivityA.this, 7, 00);`
3. In another activity, call it ActivityB:

   `AlarmReciever.setAlarm(ActivityB.this, 7, 00);`

Questions:

1. What would happen if all three kinds of setAlarm() are called? I'm concerned that they don't have the same context. Would android know they are the same `PendingIntent` and only fire once? I want it to only fire once at 7 am.
2. What if I press setAlarm button in ActivityA a few times so the same alarm is set with the same context and intent, when 7 am comes, how many would fire?
3. Say it fired at 7 am this morning and now it's 2 pm in the afternoon. I now press the button in ActivityA. The alarm would fire instantly (tested), because 7 am is a "past time". But before adding the new alarm, shouldn't the system check existing ones, and realize this is a repeating intent, and one has been fired at 7 am already? In my opinion it should ignore my setAlarm() requested at 2 pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I did experiments and I'm posting the results here in case anyone else wonders:

1. As long as the `PendingIntent` is identical, android will only fire the alarm once. You may set the alarm however many times you want, from whatever activities/classes you want.
2. One.
3. The new alarm will just trigger right way (because 7 am is a "past time"). You can write code to record the last fired date/hour (e.g. use `SharedPreferences`), and do some logic there, or depends on your situation, you may want to schedule the alarm to fire at 7 am the next day (do a plus one day on the `Calendar` object).